# cmake error : invalid escape sequence \\c

Tags: cmake

In order to make a symbol link, I run a command using cmake install. my code as below:

```
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/alib.pyd" native_pyd)
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${DESTINATION}/lib/alib.pyd" release_pyd)
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c del /f /s /q ${native_pyd} & mklink ${native_pyd}  \"${release_pyd}\"
                              COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT)")
```

Then I get an error:  "invalid escape sequence \c"
${native_pyd} string is "...\code...", so it cause the warning above.
How to fix it gracefully?

Comment: Looks like you need enclose `${native_pyd}` in quotes as it may contain spaces. `install(CODE [=[ execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c del /f /s /q "${native_pyd}" & mklink "${native_pyd}"  "${release_pyd}"
                              COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT)]=])`. For the bracket syntax see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape all the path arguments to your commands. This can be either Windows specific as you have already done and using `mklink`. To relieve yourself of the need to escape all quotes inside the `CODE` fragment you can use the bracket argument syntax. Then the command would be:

```
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/alib.pyd" native_pyd)
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${DESTINATION}/lib/alib.pyd" release_pyd)
install(CODE [=[
  execute_process(
    COMMAND cmd /c del /f /s /q "${native_pyd}" & mklink "${native_pyd}" "${release_pyd}"
    COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT
  )
]=])
```

Another solution that is platform independent and uses the CMake builtin command line tools can be formulated as follows (for a CMake version >= 3.13):

```
install(CODE [=[
  execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E remove_directory "${native_pyd}")
  execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E create_symlink "${release_pyd}" "${native_pyd}")
]=])
```